# INamedTypeSymbol inheritance relation in the Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have created INamedTypeSymbol for concrete types using [`GetTypeByMetadataName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.compilation.gettypebymetadataname?view=roslyn-dotnet)

```
INamedTypeSymbol listTypeSymbol = context.SemanticModel.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.Collections.Generic.List`1");
INamedTypeSymbol collectionTypeSymbol = context.SemanticModel.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1");
```

One of them is a symbol of a runtime type of `List<T>`, other of them is a symbol of a runtime type of `ICollection<T>`. The `List<T>` type is derived from the type of `ICollection<T>`.

**How can I check an inheritance relation for INamedTypeSymbol?**

I try to do it using a [`ClassifyConversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpextensions.classifyconversion?view=roslyn-dotnet) method

```
Conversion con = context.SemanticModel.Compilation.ClassifyConversion(listTypeSymbol, collectionTypeSymbol);
```

However this function returns *a Explicit Reference* value of conversion. I am expected to see something like *the Implicit Reference* value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a complicated one.

`` GetTypeByMetadataName("System.Collections.Generic.List`1") `` returns an *open generic type*, which is in effect a type constructor that can be used to create closed generic types with specific parameters.

It doesn't make sense to speak about conversions between open generic types; two types `A<>` and `B<>` might be differently convertible if `B<>` is declared as `B<T> : A<List<T>>` or more-complex relationships.

You can only check for convertibility between *closed* generic types that share the same type parameter. To do that, call [`Construct()`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/INamedTypeSymbol.cs,116) and pass types for the type parameters.